# Training Inception V3 using tensorflow slim on multiple machines with CPUs only

Tags: tensorflow, tf-slim

I'm trying to use the tf-slim library to train Inception V3 using multiple machines which do not have GPUs.

I'm following the tutorial given here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim. I can train using a single CPU only machine but I'm trying to figure out how to do the training using multiple machines. Its mentioned in the page that:

> This process may take several days, depending on your hardware setup.
>   For convenience, we provide a way to train a model on multiple GPUs,
>   and/or multiple CPUs, either synchrononously or asynchronously. See
>   [model_deploy](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py) for details.

I can't figure out how to use [model_deploy](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py) to train using multiple machines and neither can I find any examples to do so.

How do I go about using [model_deploy](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py) to train using multiple machines?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question, try server fault.